# Fullcalendar text in empty cells of agendaWeek

Tags: asp.net-mvc, fullcalendar

I want to have "empty" or "available" text in empty cells, but I can't seem to find anything related in Fullcalendar documentation or Google. Is there a way to achieve this? Thanks

Comment: If there's no event in a cell, then the assumption is that it's available. If you have some times which are always unavailable (not because they are occupied, but because you don't offer those times), then use the `businessHours` setting to define it. You can find that in the documentation.

Comment: @ADyson its not that I dont offer them, as I said i just want to type "available" for better understanding to the users. That they are suitable.

Comment: I see. I think you'd be better off adding a quick bit of guidance on your page to say "All empty slots are available for booking" or whatever. As you've correctly deduced, there's no way to write in an empty slot. The technical reason for this is that physically there's no single space in the HTML which represents a slot. In the agenda view, for instance, the grid you see is actually made up of 2 HTML tables overlaid on each other, one portraying the rows and one portraying the columns. So my advice to you is to find another way to represent this information about availability

Comment: @ADyson Ok thanks you, I think I will add an absolute image behind the agenda with "emty" text that seems its standing inside the emty cells.

Answer (score -1):

I advise doing this with jquery, you can iterate through all day-cells and check whether they have events or not, if they don't you append "empty" or "available" based on your criteria.

If you need a more concise answer, I need a more concise question.

Comment: a day cell is not the same as an empty slot, when looking at the "agenda" style view. A day can consist of many slots, depending on the slot duration setting. And anyway, just because a whole day has 1 or more events in it doesn't mean there isn't still some time available in that day somewhere. I don't think you've really thought this through in detail.